# Syntax issue with JavaScript / ASPX

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, resx

What is the correct syntax of this snippet:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="foo" runat="server"  ID="foo"
 OnClientClick="return confirm("'<%= GetLocalResourceObject("fooRessource") %>'");"  />
```

i'm stuck with the `'` and `"` at `OnClientClick`

Comment: you will have to use databinding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you not do this?

```
<asp:Button OnClick="foo" runat="server"  ID="foo"
OnClientClick="return myconfirm()");"  /> 

<script>
function myconfirm() 
{ 
   return confirm("<%= GetLocalResourceObject("fooRessource") %>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: @fubo, don't use the function name `confirm` as that will get confusing with `window.confirm`... you'd end up with recursion

Comment: yep - correct coder here: `function myconfirm() { return confirm("<%= GetLocalResourceObject("fooRessource") %>"); }`

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this in our code behind file?

```
foo.OnClientClick = "return confirm('" + GetLocalResourceObject("fooRessource") + "')";
```

I'm unsure how well this will work inline.